# The gettext "msgfmt" command exits with status code 0 but does not write an .MO file

Tags: internationalization, gettext, msgfmt

I've been making international-ready an application using the gettext family of tools, translating the `.po`. file to `.mo` using the `msgfmt` program. This was working at first, but as of the last few days it has stopped working. No errors are reported and the `msgfmt` program exists with a 0 status code.

I have manually checked out the `.po` file for problems with the formatting and have also run `msgfmt --checkformat` on the file, so there seems to be no problems with it. So I tried to create a simple file `x.po` to narrow down the problem. However, like the actual files in use, when running `msgfmt -o x.mo x.po`, the `x.mo` file is not written and `msgfmt` exits with a 0 status code as usual.

What is happening here?

Command: `msgfmt -o x.mo x.po`

## x.po

```
#: blah.txt:1
msgid "blah"
msgstr ""
```

## blah.txt

```
blah
```

**EDIT:** I'm sure this isn't a permissions error, because I've run the command as the root user.

Answer (score 0):

The `.po` file format requires a header.

Answer (score 0):

Mo files contains only valid translations, fuzzy or empty translation will not be included.
(I don't have enough points to add this as a comment)